# What is the meaning of something like `string[7]` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typing

While working in TypeScript today, I wanted to type a field to a string array with a set size. Though I know how to actually do this in TS, my *C instincts* made me write:

```
interface MyInterface {
  arrayField: string[7];
  // ...
}
```

I noticed that neither linter nor compiler complains about this, but it appears that `arrayField` is now simply typed to `string`. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: if you want to declare an array of specific length you should do `arrayField: Array<string> = new Array<string>(7)`. The type on the field can be omitted, since it's inferred from the assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, fredrik! As I said, "[...] I know how to actually do this in TS," but I appreciate your saying how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is a mistake. I think it should have been a `string[]`.

While this notation `string[7]` is valid from TS perspective, it does not make any sense.

`string` is just a primitive type. Because all values are objects in javascript, `string` type has also a set of allowed methods/indexed properties.

In plain javascript `"abs"[0]` returns `a`. Since TypeScript does not have a `char` type, it should be compatible with javascript. Hence `string[10000]` returns just a
`string`.

Here you can find all built in properties of `string` type:

```js
type StringProperties= {
  [Prop in keyof string]: { key: Prop, value: string[Prop] }
}
```

[image]

> How do we make a fixed length string in TS ?

Only with help of conditional types. You should  iterate over each char and put this char into array. Then you need compare the length of the array with expected string length.

See example:

```js
type ToArray<T extends string, Cache extends readonly string[] = []> =
  T extends ''
  ? Cache
  : T extends `${infer A}${infer Rest}`
  ? ToArray<Rest, [...Cache, A]>
  : Cache

type IsValid<T extends string[], Len extends number> = T['length'] extends Len ? true : false

type IsLength<T extends string, Len extends number> = IsValid<ToArray<T>, Len> // ok

type Result1 = IsLength<'hello', 6> // false
type Result2 = IsLength<'hello', 5> // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgewIICcUEMwB44ygDxCgDsATAZxnJBQEtiBzAGhgGF0BjAC1gKLMooo6UgmIAbMFRr0GAbQC6MALwxFAPhXAY8PIRIUYAciPaYAfjaceZgFy6%20BygAMAJAG96AMygoYSAF8Pb18YACUoagDnM0tEVAxsCOoWOQA6DPZuKBYkBXU7K2zgUEhYAElyADV0cVpSHD1%20Q2o6RkUWABkSJqcYYgBXAFsAI19NVTg5I3ESBhAuIyVHARhu4gsYGgHYey9a8igS8GgYSvX5rkaVlplGLp6bykHR8ZUz6tr6nGQ0TBx1A9iJoAPQgmAIADWxzK4UiA3EIAAjO9znMFlgjDxxOIEEYWAA2UHg-biQ6lU7JBEgABMqPIFwxWKgOLxLAArMStigdkA)

If you are interested in string validation techniques, you can read my [blog](https://catchts.com/hex-validation)

Comment: How do we make a fixed length string in TS?

Comment: @ShivamSingla TS strings, just like in JS, are immutable and are per definition fixed length. i.e. once created they can't be changed.

Comment: Interesting! So one can actually access specific parts of types just like you'd access fields in an object — e.g., `let x: MyInterface['arrayField']` would be a legitimate way to type `x` to the type of `arrayField`? Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Yes, you can find more explanation here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed length can be done easily:

```
interface MyInterface {
  arrayField: [string, string, string, string, string, string, string];
}
```

Well it is possible but for big integers it's pretty bad. You can write into dev tools simple code:

```js
function array(length, type = "string") {
  return `[${Array(length).fill(type)}]`
}
```